# downloading byte by byte images in angular and spring boot

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I am trying to download a file from firebase storage using spring boot server and angular, but when I hit the download API of spring boot from angular API download the complete bytes and send the complete byte to angular as a response, but for the large file this is time taking and not feasible so I want to download the file in small bytes so that the large files can also be rendered slowly, Please someone help me to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

You need `StreamingResponseBody`
Please have a look here an example how to stream images.

http://codefoolz.com/blog/java/spring/2017/07/09/Stream-Images-With-Spring.html